# How do we determine whether we are using Web API 1 or Web API 2?

Tags: asp.net, version, asp.net-web-api

**Introduce the problem**

I would like to know whether we are using Web API 1 or 2. My own packages.config indicates version 5.0.0. Is that Web API 1 or 2?

**Search, and research**

I have tried Googling the following:

> "web api 1" "web api 2"

and

> ASP.NET Web API release history

and

> ASP.NET Web API nuget

The best references seem to be these two nuget pages:

- [ASP.NET Web API Nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/AspNetWebApi) seems to indicate that anything 4.* is Web API 1,
- [Microsoft ASP.NET Web API 2.1 Nuget](http://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi/5.1.2) that anything 5.* is Web API 2.

Is that right? How would I know for sure?

Comment: `Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi -Version 5.2.7`  reference https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi/

Answer (score 30, accepted):

I think what you found seems correct. I had the same question then I had a look under my installed packages when you go "Manage Nuget packages". There was an item installed with the name "Microsoft ASP.NET WEB API 2.2". So I was able to determine my own version from there.

Comment: in VS2015, you can check packages.config file for version.

Comment: The title of the package on NuGet shows the version number: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi/

Answer (score 20):

I'm not sure what @John meant with the package name above. I'm having the following package right now:

```
Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.5.2.3
```

Based on this article http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/releases/whats-new-in-aspnet-web-api-22 I assume that starting from the package version 5.2.2 it's Web API 2.2 version.

Comment: I hate that, you check the packages file and it says it's version 5 but actually is version 2, I hate this versions hell

Comment: Same here, v5.2.3.  Thanks!

Comment: The article: "The latest ASP.NET Web API 2.2 package has the following version: '5.2.0'"

Answer (score 15):

I always try this instead -

In the controller make a method

```
public IHttpActionResult MyResult(){
    return Ok();
}
```

If you get compilation error then it is API 1.0.

If no compilation error then you are referencing API 2.0.