# How do you know the WEB API version of your project?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I am using Asp.Net MVC 4.0 Project Template then what is the web api version i will be using in my projects. I don't know how to find the web api version using in my project. How to get this version of web api?

Comment: Check the NuGet package version from packages.config.

Comment: He's asking which version of Web API he should use with MVC 4.  I guess the answer is "whichever you want".

Comment: A closely related post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23502507/465053).

Answer (score 27, accepted):

By default a MVC 4.0 template ships with version 4.0.20710.0 of WebAPI (aka Web api 1). To check this, open your solution, exapnd the webapi solution, then open the packages.config file that holds the nuget config for what you have installed. If you have not updated the packages you should see this.

```
<package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi" version="4.0.20710.0" targetFramework="net40" />
```

You can now go to the nuget website and examine the package history [here](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi/). I have copied the contents of this page below. As you can see this version of web api was release on 11th Aug 2012. This version was better known as "web api 1" after Web API 2 was release around Jan 2014. You can upgrade you MVC4 project to use Web API 2 if you wish by using the nuget update wizard.

---

Version History
Version Downloads   Last updated
Microsoft ASP.NET Web API 2.2 5.2.3 (this version)  249542  Monday, February 09 2015

Microsoft ASP.NET Web API 2.2 5.2.3-beta1   11688   Wednesday, December 17 2014

Microsoft ASP.NET Web API 2.2 5.2.2 545094  Thursday, August 28 2014

Microsoft ASP.NET Web API 2.2.2 5.2.2-rc    10649   Saturday, August 23 2014

Microsoft ASP.NET Web API 2.2 5.2.0 351005  Tuesday, July 01 2014

Microsoft ASP.NET Web API 2.2 5.2.0-rc  18499   Tuesday, May 27 2014

Microsoft ASP.NET Web API 2.1 5.1.2 416403  Wednesday, April 02 2014

Microsoft ASP.NET Web API 2.1 5.1.1 307194  Monday, February 10 2014

Microsoft ASP.NET Web API 2.1 5.1.0 201058  Friday, January 17 2014

Microsoft ASP.NET Web API 5.1.0-rc1 19761   Friday, December 06 2013

Microsoft ASP.NET Web API 2 5.0.1   152379  Thursday, February 13 2014

Microsoft ASP.NET Web API 2 5.0.0   752667  Thursday, October 17 2013

Microsoft ASP.NET Web API 5.0.0-rc1 28262   Friday, August 23 2013

Microsoft ASP.NET Web API 5.0.0-beta2   24088   Wednesday, June 26 2013

Microsoft ASP.NET Web API 5.0.0-beta1   14905   Wednesday, June 26 2013

Microsoft ASP.NET Web API 4.0.30506 648619  Thursday, May 30 2013

Microsoft ASP.NET Web API 4.0.20710 1246927 Saturday, August 11 2012

Microsoft ASP.NET Web API (RC) 4.0.20505    112922  Thursday, May 31 2012

Comment: I have checked and it is like this Microsoft.AspNet.WebAPI 5.2.2. So this is Web API 2.2?

Comment: For whoever wants to check on release notes of each version, it's available on their repo on GitHub: https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetWebStack/releases